# Debug My SQL Apache log4j issues

Tags: mysql, logging

I have a problem in my project where MYSQL table not updating after some time.We are saving log4j logs in this table.Have verified that the log4j configurations are correct.Only the log table has this issue even though other tables and log file is updating correctly.

Any pointers to debug this issue would be helpful as i dont find anything in the logs.

Is there a buffer size limit for each tables that can cause this issue 
.
Please help me with the pointers to debug Apache log4j in server leveland  debug mysql db.

Thanks
Srilakshmi

Comment: figured out the issue.The connection to MYSQL was  closed due to prolonged inactivity (8 hrs). autoReconnect=true in connection URL in log4j properties worked for me.

Comment: To Debug Apache log4j in eclipse                                                                                                          Run->Run Configurations->Server  configuration-> In JRE tab give VM argument as "-Dlog4j.debug".This will print the log4j logs.